# xCode & Permissions Problems

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, permissions

xcode problems:

I try to write a code and get "“UIViewController.h” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?" when I click unlock it's a no go because the computer isn't recognizing me as the owner.

This has never happened to me before. I'm using my own Macbook Pro running OS X ML. I'm the only user and set as Admin.

I've gone through Finder to change/double check permissions for every associated file and folder I can find (Setting myself to Read & Write), but I can't find the specific UIViewController.h file that xcode is referring to. Instead the closest thing I'm finding DetailViewController. I still did the project file and the three folders it's buried into.

I also went into terminal but pretty much anything I put in after the sudo chmod 777 command gets a "No such file or directory" even if I change the name, use forward slashes, put /* at the end or leave it out, etc.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

(Please note that I'm just starting my computer science journey. "For Dummies" instructions welcome!)

Comment: When does that error occur? While trying to compile your code?
What's the specific line of code causing the error?

Comment: It doesn't let me write anything so no particular line of code causing the problem. I open xcode and go to MasterViewController.h. and have the middle editor icon selected (bare with me & simpe language I'm still very new at this). It lets me play with the UI design in MainStoryboard just fine. In MasterViewController.h it also lets me write on the left side, but when I go to write on the right side I get that error. It also won't let me save, although my changes aren't being deleted when I close the application. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Also, I didn't clarify that this MBP is actually a Dell Vostro 1520 Hacktintosh running 10.8.3. Maybe that has something to do with this? I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you try to write to (or change) the UIViewController.h file? If yes: You should not do that, as that file belongs to the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you attempted to edit a header file belonging to a system framework in iOS which are protected against unintentional changes like this, possibly because the assistant editor in Xcode (usually shown in the right-hand editor) showed this header at some point.

The only solution here is to revert your changes unless you know exactly why you are making changes in those files.